# Manual to Quickly: application preferences?

Tags: python, documentation, preferences, canonical-quickly

Where can one find a manual to Quickly, where it is written about using (=programming, how to connect widgets in PreferencesDialogWindow with preferences, and how to use them in the application) application preferences? Official tutorial (both in "quickly tutorial" and [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/quickly.1.html)) tells nothing about it, although it is a very important aspect (they both are very short in general...).

(I mean the standard ubuntu-application template)

I tried to ask it on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294342/manual-to-quickly-application-preferences), but didn't get an answer, so I hope to get a response here.

Maybe it would be easier for someone to just tell how it works, than point out a guide, in this case you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think [Quickly's documentation](http://people.ubuntu.com/~mhall119/quickly/template_development/get_started.html) should have what you're looking for. If not, maybe you'll find it in [this tutorial](http://rickspencer3.com/quickly-getting-started.html).

Comment: I don't think that any of those links can help, please look through them.